# How should I handle unfunny, frivolous comments?

Tags: discussion, comment-flags

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815073/problems-solving-recurrence-tn-4tn-4-3log-n), there is the comment "The answer is eleven. (source: I'm a website developer)."  This is straight noise, so I want to flag it for removal.  Should I flag this as "not constructive"?  "Too chatty"?  Some custom flag reason?  Should I not flag it at all?

Comment: As an aside, when questions start asking about theorms and really look like they want to use funny greek letters in the body... I'd be tempted to toss a flag on the question itself to migrate it to CS.SE.

Comment: @MichaelT: I agree, but that seems like a losing battle.

Comment: You should sit down and think about why this matters so much to you.  Also, think about bunny rabbits.  Not enough thought is put into bunnies.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Either "not constructive", "too chatty", or "the answer is forty-two, not eleven (source: h2g2)" works just fine.

Comment: If I could -42 every 42 joke, I would.  Instead, I must suffer with a measly -1 :(

Answer (score 8):

I'd flag such a comment as *not constructive*.

See [A guide to moderating comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237978/a-guide-to-moderating-comments/237980#237980); it is a joke made at the author's expense:

> "pithy" jokes at the authors' expense, "snarky" advice meant more to score points with the commenter's peers than to inform or educate.

The comment is there to score humour points with peers. Nothing is lost with the comment gone.

Comment: I figured "not constructive" was for "that's flamebait" or "you're being a jerk."  But I guess this stuff isn't actually judged in isolation, so almost anything would do?

Comment: @tmyklebu: anything that is making a joke out of the question is, in my book, not constructive. The joke is aimed at everyone else; *look, aren't I funny!* That's great in a chatroom, but in comments it is at best noise.

Comment: @tmyklebu: "not constructive" really means "this adds no value to the discussion", which actually covers a lot of ground.

Comment: @tmyklebu: example I flagged yesterday on a homework question starting with *Write a program that..* and nothing but the assignment (no code). The comment, in full, was *Done..... Wrote it.*. Funny, but the author of the question thought that the commenter was serious and asked them where it was posted. The comment was noise and the joke made at the expense of the OP.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Sure, but that's a garbage comment on any question I can imagine.  For this one I'm not so sure.  In any case, I understand how to use these flags now; thanks to the both of you.